# Find only certain elements in table with Beatiful soup

Tags: python, regex, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm triying to get the href attributes from a table in this [web](http://meteo.navarra.es/estaciones/descargardatos.cfm). I have this code to get all of the links but i want to filter so i only access to the href for 'Automaticas' not the 'Manuales'

```
# Fetch URL
url = 'http://meteo.navarra.es/estaciones/descargardatos.cfm'

request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'utf-8')

# Response has UTF-8 charset header, and HTML body which is UTF-8 encoded
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# Parse with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a',{'href': re.compile(r'descargardatos_estacion.*')}):
    estacion = 'http://meteo.navarra.es/estaciones/' + a.attrs.get('href')
    print(estacion)
    # descarga_csvs(estacion)
```

The src above for 'Automaticas' and 'Manuales' are different but i don't know how to filter them.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output? All `href` values containing `descargardatos_estacion`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the href atributtes which have an src = '*.autoomatica.giff' above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By preference I would use css selectors for speed, and simply filter on img with src containing `automatica`. Then move to the adjacent `a` tag, with an adjacent sibling combinator (+), and extract the `href`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://meteo.navarra.es/estaciones/descargardatos.cfm')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
automaticas = ['http://meteo.navarra.es/estaciones/' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('img[src*=automatica] + a')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
for img in soup.find_all(lambda x: x.name == 'img' and 'automatica.gif' in x['src']):
    print(img.next_sibling.next_sibling['href'])
```

Notes:

- `soup.find_all(lambda x: x.name == 'img' and 'automatica.gif' in x['src'])` - fetches all `img` nodes that contain `automatica.gif` in the `src` attribute
- `img.next_sibling.next_sibling['href']` - gets the `href` value of the second sibling of each found `img` tag.